# Is there a CSS3 selector for text nodes?

Tags: html, css

I want set style to  **records per page** text but  this text is not `a` tag or `span` or any tag. How can I select this text with css?

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="dynamic-table_length">
<label>
<select aria-controls="dynamic-table" size="1" name="dynamic-table_length"><option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
 records per page
</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it normal that your label includes the select ? Best way is use label only for text next to the input. <select></select><label> records per page</label>

Comment: use two passes to change the style - one for the label (which also affects the select options since they are within the label and then another for the select itself, for example -   $('#dynamic-table_length label').css('color','red');  
  $('[name=dynamic-table_length]').css('color','black');  which creatyes a red label with black selection options

Comment: gavgrif  : Ok. This is right . I can do this with css such as your comment